# How to configure the feature module block within tabs or [container] tabs in joomla?

Tags: joomla, tabs

We are working on our new joomla website. If anyone could give some guidance around the difference between the tab module and [container] tab module it would be greatly appreciated.

Specifically, how to configure the feature module block with tabs or [container] tabs in joomla.

Also, what is the difference between the tabs and [container] tab module?

Thanks!!!

Comment: This is not a core Joomla! feature. Can you specify which template and/or module you are using?

Comment: Uber. [Container] tabs and feature module.